# How can I organize angularjs factories/services/config/controllers files in different locations?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

Currently I have this structure:

```
index.html
>views
   login-view.html
   report-view.html
>JS
   config.js
   >controllers
       loginCtrl.js
       reportCtrl.js
   >factories
       firebaseRefFactory.js
```

In config.js I have the routing of the templates, and the injection of firebase and such.
I can use the controllers properly, but if I try to use a factory, I get the Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

My index.html

```
<head>
    <!-- STYLES-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/modifier.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/layout.css">
    <!-- ANGULAR -->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
     <script src="JS/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.2/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
    <!-- FIREBASE -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.17/firebase.js"></script>
    <!-- ANGULARFIRE -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.0/angularfire.js"></script>
    <!-- CONFIG -->
    <script src="JS/config.js"></script>
    <!-- FACTORIES -->
    <script src="JS/factories/firebaseRefFactory.js"></script>
    <!-- CONTROLLERS -->
    <script src="JS/controllers/login.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/controllers/reporte.js"></script>

</head>
```

My config.js

```
angular.module('Demo', ['firebase','ui.router']).config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');

$stateProvider.
state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'VIEWS/login-view.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl'
}).
state('report', {
    url: '/report',
    templateUrl: 'VIEWS/report-view.html',
    controller: 'reportCtrl',
}); }]);
```

My loginCtrl where I want to use my factory

```
angular.module('Demo').controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', 'firebaseRefFactory', function($scope, firebaseRefFactory){
alert(firebaseRefFactory.getRef()); }]);
```

My factory

```
angular.module('Demo').factory('firebaseRefFactory', ['', function(){
return function getRef(){
    var text = "132";
    return text;
} }]);
```

I tried changing the order of the scripts in the html file, and injecting the factory in the angular module in the config file.

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.module('Demo').factory('firebaseRefFactory', ['', function(){
return function getRef(){
    var text = "132";
    return text;
} }]);
```

Modified to this:

```
angular.module('Demo').factory('firebaseRefFactory', function(){
return{
    getRef: function(){
        var text;
        text = '123';
        return text;
    }
    };
});
```

Thanks to TheSharpieOne, this guide us useful: https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide

Comment: Quick note to second the recommendation for the John Papa styleguide… I learnt so much from reading this!

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty arguement in your DI:

```
angular.module('Demo').factory('firebaseRefFactory', function(){
return function getRef(){
    var text = "132";
    return text;
});
```

Maybe try that? What you have there should work other than that. Try to avoid the array notation for DI and use ng-annotate if minifying your JS.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use requirejs. Requirejs is really good option for separating js in differnet files as all required js files are configured in its main.js.

link for [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html):

[image]